# Raku crashes, "left argument in overloaded package Perl6::Object"

Tags: raku

I'm writing an excel xlsx spreadsheet with Raku and inline::Perl5.

When I write a line like

```
$file-location-ws.write($row, 2, $csv);
```

Raku crashes with the cryptic error message

> Operation "eq": no method found,  left argument in overloaded package
> Perl6::Object,    right argument has no overloaded magic at
> /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.0/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Worksheet.pm line 2020.
>
> in method invoke-parent at
> /home/con/.perl6/sources/130449F27E85303EEC9A19017246A5ED249F99E4
> (Inline::Perl5) line 674   in sub many-args at
> /usr/lib/perl6/site/sources/D38010D24322CE1B1E6FFD8A463F23ED864152E9
> (Inline::Perl5::ClassHOW) line 195   in block  at 8.make_xlsx.p6
> line 100

but if I replace $csv with a literal string of the filename `'Pumbaa Validation Plate 1 samplesheet.csv'` thus

```
$file-location-ws.write($row, 2, 'Pumbaa Validation Plate 1 samplesheet.csv');
```

it works just fine.  Obviously, this isn't a solution, since `$csv` will change.

Why is this error happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Feels like a bug to me to be reported to the [`Inline::Perl5`](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5/issues) issues, which you appear [to have done already](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5/issues/132)

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen yep I fixed the problem and I closed the issue

Comment: FYI, niner has reopened the issue with "I think this is still an issue in IP5. ... Will have to investigate.". Hopefully some combo of fixing IP5 code and/or its error messages and/or its doc and/or P5 will come of this SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the `write` function expects a variable/container of type `Str` but is getting an `IO::Path`.

This is easily solved by assigning the variable to be written as a `Str` type.

The issue was that the error message gave no hint whatsoever of this.

Comment: "The issue was that the error message gave no hint" of solution. Indeed. FYI Larry Wall has emphasized in P6 culture that we consider [LTA](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#index-entry-LTA)s as potentially issues (bugs) in and of themselves, separate from an underlying error. So this SO plausibly involves *two* issues -- the error and the message. (Perhaps doc too.) In this case niner is investigating so I don't think there's a need to file anything further for now. But please know it would have been reasonable if you had decided to file a *separate* issue about the message.